# how to get the user email from the applyActionCode in Firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have my own custom server that also records users. So what I want to achieve is, after a user registers, Then I will generate a custom token by `signInWithCustomToken`, then send a `sendEmailVerification` to them for verifying.

Here is how I generate the custom token from my backend

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().createCustomToken(id, additionalClaims)
```

Then in my front end, it will `signInWithCustomToken` right after they registered. (this is to get the `user` for `sendEmailVerification`)

```
await axios
    .post(`/authorization/sign-up`, {
      username: inputData.username,
      password: inputData.password,
    })
    .then(async (response) => {
      const auth = getAuth();
      signInWithCustomToken(auth, response.data.content.token)
      .then(async(userCredential) => {
          await updateEmail(userCredential.user, inputData.username)
          const actionCodeSettings = {
            url: `https://domain host/test?email=${inputData.username}`
          };
          await sendEmailVerification(userCredential.user, actionCodeSettings)
          navigate("/"); //login page
      })
    })
    .catch((error) => toast(error.message));
} else {
  toast("Please input valid data");
}
```

In my Login Backend I will check my database's user, whether their email has been verified or not. So if its not verified, the login will be rejected

```
select * from user where user = foo and password = foo and isEmailVerified = true
```

In my front-end `verify-email` page :

```
console.log("verifying email")
const mode = searchParams.get('mode') // mode = verifyEmail
const oobCode = searchParams.get('oobCode')
const auth = getAuth()
applyActionCode(auth, oobCode).then(() => {
    //how to update my backend based on the user's email
})
```

Then in my Backend I will check the `decodedToken.isEmailVerified`, if its false, I will force them to activate their email first.

So, after the user click the activation link, it will be redirected to my `verify-email` page, which then will also update the status of the user in my database. But, I notice that the `applyActionCode` function returns `Promise<void>`.

For example if I register my email through my PC/Laptop, then I confirm the verify email through my phone / table / other device, then I won't be able to get the `currentUser` to retrieve some data, ex. their email.

I also cannot put the email into the `continueUrl` parameter right? since the user might change the parameter themself.

So How can I get the user's email safely after `applyActionCode`?
Or do I just redirect them back to the login page, then each time after they click login, I will compare the `decodedToken.isEmailVerified` vs my database's `isEmailVerified` ?

Comment: `signInWithCustomToken` does not _generate_ token. Can you please clarify your flow and also share complete block of code so its easier to know where are you trying to get the data required? Also, are you essentially trying prevent users who have not verified their email from logging in?

Comment: ok, I will put some of my backend code and front end code. Please wait a min

Comment: hi @Dharmaraj i've added some backend and frontend code, and verify more of the flow. What I want to do is to update my own database's user after that user complete the email verification.